# What are HttpRuntime.Cache entries "__AppStartPage__" for?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, httpruntime.cache

In my asp.net webforms app, I've added code to the Application_Startup method to schedule a couple of daily and weekly tasks.  That all works fine.  I decided to add a ListBox on my maintenance page to show me what the HttpRuntime.Cache contents are - specifically the TaskName and Expiration time are of interest, as I was having issues with tasks "disappearing" (But no longer - I changed the IIS Application Pool timeout to avoid that).  SO, my question is: I am seeing 2 Cache entries that I don't understand (the keys are):

1. **AppStartPage**~/_appstart.cshtml   and,
2. **AppStartPage**~/_appstart.vbhtml

I don't have either of those anywhere in my project, so I don't know where they come from.
Is this a concern? Normal behavior?  Just seems "off" somehow.